# 301 Redirect Chain Caused By Custom Post Type [WORDPRESS]

Tags: seo, wordpress, 301-redirect, ahrefs

We're using Pods to create custom post types. We needed to redirect an existing page to its new location under the custom post type, but now Ahrefs is detecting a redirect chain.

[www.example.com/mainpage](http://www.example.com/mainpage) was 301'd to [www.example.com/posttype/mainpage](http://www.example.com/posttype/mainpage)

However, it's chaining from example.com/mainpage to example.com/?p=123, then to the target URL.

Comment: Please post your redirection (htaccess or other) code here.  OTOH, if ahrefs is saying it, its probably true